# Android View Pager Validation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Tried to  implemented view pager containing 5 fragments, each fragments contains edit text which are mandatory. if any of the edit text is empty we must no allow the user to swipe to next page but the user can swipe back to previous page.

i am struggling on applying the validation please help on this

Comment: You should think about extending the ViewpPager widget and override the listeners associated with scrolling in between fragments. That way, if the textviews are empty, then you can prevent the user from scrolling forward.

Comment: i have tried disabling the scrolling to next page on page scrolled listener but whar happens is the next fragments starts to load and it gets disabled half point